# Mysql Query that gets records that don't belong to set

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables (tb_book and tb_page).
Tb_page contains the summary of each page of a book. The fields in this table are page_number, summary, book_id.

| page_number | summary | book_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Summary book 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Summary book 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Summary book 1 | 1 |
| 4 | Summary book 1 | 1 |
| 5 | Summary book 1 | 1 |

tb_book contains a list of the pages that are available for a book. The fields in the table are book_id, book_name, start_page, end_page. As you can see, this table indicates a set of pages (start_page, end_page); however, you can have gaps between these sets.

| book_id | book_name | start_page | end_page |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | book 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | book 1 | 5 | 5 |

I have to do a query that gets all the pages that are not in the book sequences. (if there is more than 1 sequence per book, it has to be the difference). Using this example data, the records I should get are 3 and 4 because they don't belong to the sequence 1 to 2 and 5 to 5.
Queries I'm using

```
Select page_number from tb_page where book_id = (parameter used #1);
Select start_page, end_page from tb_book where book_id = (parameter used #1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tb_book;
CREATE TABLE tb_book(page_number INT,   summary VARCHAR(20), book_id INT);
INSERT INTO tb_book VALUES
(1,     'Summary book 1',  1),
(2,     'Summary book 1',  1),
(3,     'Summary book 1',  1),
(4,     'Summary book 1',  1),
(5,     'Summary book 1',  1);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tb_page;
CREATE TABLE tb_page(book_id INT,       book_name VARCHAR(20),       start_page INT,     end_page INT);
INSERT INTO tb_page VALUES
(1,     'book 1',  1,       2),
(1,     'book 1',  5,       5);


SELECT tb_book.*
FROM tb_book
LEFT JOIN tb_page ON tb_page.book_id = tb_book.book_id
                 AND tb_book.page_number between tb_page.start_page and tb_page.end_page
WHERE tb_page.book_id is null
;
```

output:

```
+ ---------------- + ------------ + ------------ +
| page_number      | summary      | book_id      |
+ ---------------- + ------------ + ------------ +
| 3                | Summary book 1 | 1            |
| 4                | Summary book 1 | 1            |
+ ---------------- + ------------ + ------------ +
```

This query is, for every page in `tb_book`, trying to see if it is in a range defined in `tb_page`.

The where clause (`WHERE tb_page.book_id is null`) selects only those rows that do not have a range registered.

see also: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a15bbbec5cde90381c9a25192c4b3fe)

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` (on the right tables, of course) is a very reasonable solution.

However, `NOT EXISTS` is almost a direct translation of your question ("I have to do a query that gets all the pages that are not in the book sequences") into SQL:

```
select b.*
from tb_page p
where not exists (select 1
                  from tb_book b
                  where b.book_id = p.book_id and
                        p.page_number >= b.start_page and
                        p.page_number <= b.end_page
                 );
```

For either version, an index on `tb_book(book_id, start_page, end_page)` will help performance.